# Change Boolean Output

Tags: python, boolean

I'm trying to change the output of Boolean values.

For example if I've got something like:

```
3 == 3
```

I don't want it to return `True`, but to return something that I specify like `Correct`

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: use an if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def equivalence(a,b):

    if(a==b):
       print("Correct")
    else:
       print("Incorrect")
```

Then you can call this function.

```
equivalence(5,5) #This will print "Correct"
equivalence(5,6) #This will print "Incorrect"
```

If you actually want to change what `==` actually *does*, you would have to override the operator class `__eq__`. But this can quickly become out-of-hand if you are just starting out with programming.

**Edit to address OP's comment:**

What I wrote can be replaced to anything. You can do something as simple as:

```
if(2+3<5-7):
   print("Correct")
else:
   print("Incorrect")
```

The general format is:

```
if(condition):
   #What to do if condition is true.
else:
   #What to do if condition is false.
```

You don't even need a function to do this. You can use if-statements on their own like what I did above.

**Second edit:**

Okay now I see what you want. Here's what you can do. It might be a little complex but bear with me.

Create a function such as this. You can name it whatever you want as long as you're consistent:

```
def booleanizer(condition):
   if(condition):
      print("Correct")
      return True
   else:
      print("Incorrect")
      return False
```

Now, wherever you have a conditional statement where you are trying to print "correct" or "incorrect", just wrap the conditional statement in `booleanizer` as follows:

Say you have `2+3<5-7` and you want to "booleanize" it.

```
booleanizer(2+3<5-7) #this prints "Incorrect"
```

Or you could apply this to any conditional

```
booleanizer("This"=="This") #Prints "Correct"
booleanizer(7<5) #Prints "Incorrect"
```

etc...

Comment: Hi rb612. Thanks for your answer. I am definitely a beginner with programming. I understand parts of the code you mentioned. such as def and equivalence, it's more about calling functions which confuses me. I not sure if it will still help as I think I might've worded my question wrong. Basically there is a line of code that says: 'print 3 + 2 < 5 - 7' and this returns False, I want it to say Incorrect. In other words the 3 == 3 example, probably wasn't relevant to the question as there is no == in the code. Oops :)

Comment: No problem! We're here to help. Please see my edit which should address your exact question. If you are satisfied with my answer, please click the checkmark to mark as answered. To answer your question regarding calling functions, you can post a new question and link to it here, and I could answer it.

Comment: you can also use `print "Correct" if 2+3 < 5-7 else "Incorrect"`

Comment: @KerryM-R yep, and that's what's great about Python as a dynamic language. But for a beginning programmer, I think it's best to teach the standard if/else statements.

Comment: Ok, so I believe that the question is almost solved. However, the suggestions seem to mostly apply to one condition. Since I multiple conditions throughout the code, I need a way of applying the method across all the conditions that are in the script. So, instead of getting a boolean response of "True", I want it to say "Correct". Thanks again everyone for all your comments so far. I guess the main thing that I'm trying to achieve is replace boolean values 'True' and 'False' with custom values, like 'Correct' and 'Incorrect'.

Comment: Thanks rb612, just saw your comment, I'll try it as soon as I get home and let you know if it works.

Comment: Ok, so I've put the changed code in the description. I've made a change to the code given by rb612 where instead of returning true or false, I made it return "", which would print nothing otherwise on line 1, it would print Correct, then on line 2, it would print false. Unless, there is another way to stop returning true or false in the output, then I'll accept rb612 answer as the best answer.

Comment: @JoshuaStokes You can remove the lines that say `return` alltogether. In other words, those are not necessary. The reason why I put them in is so that you can still use the function to verify a boolean expression. But that seems to not be something you need so you can remove those two lines from your code (the return lines)

Comment: Hi rb612. If I don't put the return lines in, It would say none. Eg: for a correct answer, on line 1 it would say correct and line 2 it would say none, that's why I did return ""

Comment: @JoshuaStokes are you using Python shell to execute? If this is the case, that's a bit how it is and there's no way around it. What you could do is write `x=booleanizer(1==2)` or set it to a variable each time you call it. That should suppress the output `None`.

Comment: Hi rb612 So, should I put print x at the end of the script... I'm a little confused.

Comment: Hi rb612. Just worked out that I don't need print x as the print statement as they were already in the booleanizer function. I will mark your second answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [shorties way](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to do it is:

```
"Correct" if 3 == 3 else "Incorrect"
```

There is no good way to change behaivour of `print(True)` output.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = float(input("enter a Number between 1 - 5: "))

Correct = False

while (not Correct):

    if x == 3:
        Correct = True
        print("Correct")

    else:
        print("sorry guess again!")
        x = float(input("enter a Number between 1 - 5: "))
```

Comment: This is not what OP was asking. OP is talking about a generalized example of equating two values and instead of just saying "true" or "false" will print a custom string.